# Is Weddingnuts.com a StackExchange site or an SO clone?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Take a look at the site (Hat tip to cwrea for [finding it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites/67#67)!):

- http://www.weddingnuts.com

It sure has a lot of similarities to SO!

- http://www.weddingnuts.com/badges/
- https://stackoverflow.com/badges/
- http://weddingnuts.com/faq/
- https://stackoverflow.com/faq

But it seems to use Python:

- http://pipeboost.com/GetReport.asp?URL=http://weddingnuts.com/

And it doesn't use OpenID directly for signin:

- https://superuser.com/users/login?returnurl=/

Instead, Weddingnuts uses RPX to interface with OpenID and other auth systems:

- https://weddingnuts.rpxnow.com/openid/v2/signin?token_url=http://example.com/sso/rpx/

Then again, DocType is in the League of Justice... so who knows.

What do you think: is Weddingnuts.com a SE site or an SO clone?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: Also see http://www.googlewavez.com

Comment: Yah, that's the same engine as weddingnuts

Comment: http://wickedawesomewallpapers.com/

Comment: Let's hope they have some kind of patent/trademark on look and feel they can enforce

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Clone.

Searching for a tag (`[venues]`) does not show the same tags page that SO does.

- **Weddingnuts**: `http://www.weddingnuts.com/?term=%5Bvenues%5D
- **Meta Stackoverflow**: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug

---

It appears to be built with the same engine as our dear old friend CNProg.com.

The logo for Wedding Nuts is at `/content/images/logo2.png`. Guess what is at `/content/images/logo1.png`?

**Edit:**  This use to be the CNProg logo. I will still leave the tag here just in case it decides to come online...

http://weddingnuts.com/content/images/logo1.png

---

**Edit: Turns out debug mode has been turned off, so all of this does not really apply any more**

I know any website can have 'fancy' URLs, but the URLs Wedding Nuts uses do seem very Django-y, especially consider CNProg.com is written with Django.

A quick search finds that [GearCult](http://www.gearcult.com) is hosted on the same server has Wedding Nuts (and Google Wavez). Whoever is running these sites really has a thing for **duplicating** other popular websites in Django. You can confirm that it runs Django by [making it 404](http://gearcult.com/asdf). By the looks of the urls.py, it doesnt look like whoever made these sites is a very good programmer!

---

**Edit: Turns out debug mode has been turned off, so all of this does not really apply any more**

Interestingly enough, both WickedAwesomeWallpapers and Gearcult are being run in debug mode. This means if you [404](http://wickedawesomewallpapers.com/404), you will be presented with a list of all the valid urls, as regex.

You can also take advantage of the wonderful Django tracebacks to take a look at small snippits of his code and server settings by forcing an error. Try [this one](http://wickedawesomewallpapers.com/render/s/):

> **/var/www/django/wickedwall/forum/views.py in render:**
>
> ```
> def render(request, slug="", hue=0, saturation=0, lightness=0):
>
>    if hue != 0:
>       hue = int(hue)
>
>    wallpaper = Wallpaper.objects.get(slug = slug)
>
>    return render_to_response('render.html', {
>         "wallpaper" : wallpaper,
>         "hue" : hue,
>         "saturation" : saturation,
>         "lightness" : lightness,
> ```

Using these, you can confirm that both WickedAwesomeWallpapers and Gearcult are owned/ran by 'robstar'. Just take a look at the 'ADMINS' setting from their settings.py:

```
ADMINS  (('Rob', 'robstar@gmail.com'),)
```

Then a quick look on his [twitter](http://twitter.com/robstar) page reveals this robstar fellow is the 'mastermind' behind Wedding Nuts and Google WaveZ.

Interestingly enough, it does not look like CNProg and these sites are run by the same person. A simple domain whois on CNProg.com shows that the *domain* belongs to "Chen Gang".  <sub>A whois on weddingnuts.com is pointless because it was registered through a proxy</sub>

Comment: gearcult looks so much like digg.

Comment: CNProg.com also has a "Feedback" link on its left side that looks exactly the same.  Nice find!

Comment: l33t skillz

Comment: Looks like they deleted that logo1.png image.

Comment: And those sites are no longer running in debug mode (I've never touched Django)?  I guess the site owner has read our little thread!

Comment: I think so Jarrod!  The http://weddingnuts.com/content/images/logo1.png file was also deleted - it used to be the logo for CNPROG.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/100387 ?

Comment: http://twitter.com/robstar/status/2484737556 Confirms he built wedding nuts.

Answer (score 34):

Heh, in their [question page's javascript](http://www.weddingnuts.com/content/js/util.post.js), my name appears in a comment (in code I wrote a long time ago):

```
// {"Id":6,"PostId":38589,"CreationDate":"an hour ago","Text":"hello there!","UserDisplayName":"Jarrod Dixon","UserUrl":"/users/3/jarrod-dixon","DeleteUrl":null}
var renderComment = function(jDiv, json) {
```

That's before we minified our js and before we did a major refactoring on question/answer comments (in part to facilitate comment votes, in part because I was on something when I wrote it).

At first, I was angry, but then I went and downloaded some copyrighted music.  THE CIRCLE OF THEFT GOES ROUND AND ROUND!

Comment: *copies this answer into a code comment*

Comment: @Isaac Waller - it's a downside, but also an upside - you can see how any site does a cool feature.

Comment: they paid the price

Answer (score 8):

Interesting just how much of the *copy* (as in text content) is taken directly from SO.  Check out the Faq page to see what I mean.  It's almost word for word.

It's also easily the closest *functional* clone I've seen.  Whoever built is has spent a significant amount of time at SO.  I'd give good odds it's a 10K user (with this much attention to detail, they want to clone the mod tools, too).  Anyone gonna step forward and claim it?

**Update**
Looks like it runs [cahoots](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cahoots/) (note the heart shaped favorites image in this [screen shot](http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=213565)).

Comment: Yah but if they copied the actual text, it stops being a clone and becomes a copyright violation.  I wonder if they also copied the css outright as well...

Comment: Nah, screenshots are different and it's in PHP. I doubt someone would host PHP behind a Python server. Anybody can use a heart shaped gif (he might even have stolen from cahoots)

Comment: Interesting yes, and it's the text content that led me to the sites.  I was actually trying to see if any of the *Stack Exchange* sites had been indexed by Google yet, figuring that ppl might not have changed some of the stock text!

Comment: Of course I might've been **naive** in assuming that any of the *real* Stack Exchange sites are allowing themselves to be indexed yet ;-)

Comment: Whois says GoDaddy anon wiper, so that makes it a little harder to figure out who owns the site who might also be a 10K SOpedian.

Answer (score 4):

It's a clone. There are few signs. Like the url to the questions doesnt use dashes for space. The css files are different and more.

Answer (score 4):

The resemblance is... uncanny. But, all the questions are *months* old. And even if those dates were faked for some bizarre reason, [there's this](http://digg.com/educational/Weddingnuts_com_A_Reputation_Based_social_forum).

Comment: And the tweets from June and July at http://twitter.com/robstar

Answer (score 3):

So close and yet so far. It falls on the [Uncanny Valley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_valley) of website clones. It is very very close, but it feels totally weird.

Answer (score 3):

wickedawesomewallpapers.com is running Django: http://wickedawesomewallpapers.com/terms

(in case they fix it, that page currently says:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:
>     GET Request URL:
>     http://wickedawesomewallpapers.com/terms
>
> Using the URLconf defined in urls,
>   Django tried these URL patterns, in
>   this order:
>
> 1. ^$
> 2. [...]
> 3. ^media/(?P.*)$
>
> The current URL, terms, didn't match
>   any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you
>   have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False,
>   and Django will display a standard 404
>   page.

Hey, I found the [admin login](http://wickedawesomewallpapers.com/adman/))

Comment: They have a double-agent in their server settings!

Comment: I don't get the connection to wickedawesomewallpapers.com?

Comment: @kanamekun: If you force an error on WAW ( http://wickedawesomewallpapers.com/render/a/ ) and scroll all the way down to the Django settings, you will notice that the admin value is set to (('Rob', 'robstar@gmail.com'),). Robstar is the owner of wedding nuts and googlewavez (see his twitter account). Also, doing the same for GearCult (which is hosted on the same server as Weddingnuts. http://gearcult.com/tech/a/ ) reveals the admin is once again 'Rob'.

Answer (score 3):

http://socialwire.ca/?p=42

Interesting!

> Social Wire has entered the social
>   forum space with a unique engine of
>   our own.  Similar to other Q&A sites
>   out there, GoogleWaveZ takes the forum
>   to the next level.  Blending
>   questions, answers, wikis, reputation
>   and a voting system to create a social
>   forum totally run by its users.
>
> Social Wire Inc. will be
>   white-labeling this engine and
>   launching a self serve version to the
>   public in Early 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting! 
Apparently, smart guys got CNProg code running in the first time. Nice job on UI tweaking and English translation.

Ah? No sign of CNProg!? hmm.. can i say these are rip-off CNProg? oh.. they even stole my code and said "[unique own engine](http://socialwire.ca/?p=42)"..

Comment: Link seems duff.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to check, go to

```
http://{website}/users/flair/1.html
```

None of the copycat sites, as far as I know, have user "flair".

Answer (score 0):

I love how it is prepopulated with fake users and content. If you look around on the user pages of some users, like these ones:

- http://www.weddingnuts.com/users/4/babyblue
- http://www.weddingnuts.com/users/33/iluvtiffany

... you can see that their reputation and the number of votes they've received + accepted answers + etc don't add up.